# Static variables in a Javascript class

Tags: javascript, object, static-methods, static-members

Is there a *correct* way to create **private** static javascript variables (and functions) that do not change no matter how many times you create `new Obj`?

This is what I tried and it seems to *work*:

```
var ObjClass = (function(){

    var static_var = 0; //private static variable
    var static_fn = function(){ return static_var; }; //private static function

    return function(){
        ++static_var;
        var thisNumber = static_var;
        this.getThisNumber = function(){
             return thisNumber;
        }
        this.getStaticNumber = static_fn; //making static fn public
    }

})();

var obj1 = new ObjClass;
var obj2 = new ObjClass;
var obj3 = new ObjClass;

console.log(obj1.getThisNumber()); //output `1`
console.log(obj1.getStaticNumber()); //output `3`
console.log(obj2.getThisNumber()); //output `2`
console.log(obj2.getStaticNumber()); //output `3`
console.log(obj3.getThisNumber()); //output `3`
console.log(obj3.getStaticNumber()); //output `3`​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/YFmKm/)

Or is there some *other* ***better*** way?

Comment: static_var *changes* every time you create an object???

Comment: you're missing the `()` after each call to `new ObjClass`.

Comment: @Bergi I mean they are the **same** from every class.

Comment: @jbabey you do not need it....

Comment: @jbabey Incorrect, it is perfectly legal to instantiate an object without parenthesis.

Comment: This seems to be the widely-accepted way to implement statics in JS, yes.

Comment: Do those static members need to be read-only and/or non-deletable?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas well the idea would be as any `static` type in a normal Object oriented class.

Comment: @Neal Well, I don't do other languages, so I wouldn't know how `static` works `:)`. Tell please...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas a static member is a member of a class that does not get instantiated for every object created by that class. essentially it belongs to the class itself, not the objects built from that class.

Comment: @jbabey Is it possible to change the value of such a member subsequently? Is it possible to delete such a member subsequently?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes they can be changed, but usually not deleted. the classic example is a counter that keeps track of how many objects that have been created from the class, as Neal shows in this example.

Comment: @jbabey But can they be changed from outside code?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas if they are **private** static, they cannot, as the ones in my question are **private**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx note this is written for C#, but static classes/members exist in many OO languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct approach to create private static variables.

However, I would treat the `static_fn` different. It seems you want it to be public.

1. It should be on your "class"es prototype as it does not interact with private instance variables
2. It even does not interact with instances at all. The usual approach is to put such a function/variable on the "class" itself, i.e. the constructor in JS. As the constructor is a `Function` object, it can be extended with properties as any other js object.

```
var ObjClass = (function closure(){

    var static_var = 0; //static private (scoped) variable
    function static_fn(){ return static_var; }; //static private (scoped) function

    function ObjClass() {
        var thisNumber = ++static_var; // private instance variable
        this.getThisNumber = function() { // public instance method
            return thisNumber; // "privileged" to access scoped instance variables
        };
    }
    ObjClass.getStaticNumber = static_fn; // make the static_fn public
    return ObjClass;
})();



var obj1 = new ObjClass;
var obj2 = new ObjClass;
console.log(ObjClass.getStaticNumber()); //output `2`
var obj3 = new ObjClass;
console.log(ObjClass.getStaticNumber()); //output `3`

console.log(obj1.getThisNumber()); //output `1`
console.log(obj2.getThisNumber()); //output `2`
console.log(obj3.getThisNumber()); //output `3`
```

Comment: --Bergi I changed my question and added the word **private** to the static idea. Yes, in my case the function is public, but the data `static_var` should still be private

Comment: `+1` -- this seems to reflect better on how the object **should** be created :-) Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the static_var is private and can only accessed from inside the closure. From it you will "export" the public constructor function and the public, static getter function.

Comment: Bergi -- I do not think there is a reason for naming the closure function and the return function. What is your reason for doing so?

Comment: Just for talking to you about *the "closure" function* :-) Read http://kangax.github.com/nfe/ and leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously used this trivial approach to create static variables, except that they're private.

```
function MyClass() {

    var static = this.constructor.static = this.constructor.static || {
        var1: defValue,
        ...
    }

    static.var1 = ... ;
}
```

i.e. just store the static variables as properties of the classes' primary constructor function.

Comment: Are there any advantages to this? And won't that make all of the statics public? Let us say I want one or two **private** static variables?

Comment: the statics here are _kind of_ hidden, but you can't really have it both ways - it's hard (albeit not impossible) to have a variable both shared across multiple instances, yet also hidden in closure scope.  You'd have to wrap an outer closure around the whole thing.

Comment: Well that is sort of what I do in my OP. And I think that @Bergi's post sums it up pretty well of what _could_ be done.

Comment: @Neal the main advantage is simplicity.

Comment: Haha **simplicity** I do not know the word :-P

Comment: Finally... a solution that works perfectly with AngularJs when controllers are called from other controllers. Thank you!

Comment: @submind NB: ISTR that `static` is a reserved word in ES6, so use `_static` or similar.